Three-dimensional referencing
I have a dataset that looks roughly like this:


I'm trying to make a simplified table that pulls from that dataset:


Looking at just Column D in my simplified table — the goal is to return the "Monday" dates corresponding to the matched up episode numbers and the "TIMING LOCK" cells that corresponds to each one.
I have a formula that successfully returns the appropriate array of dates if the "TIMING LOCK" cells were in the same row as the numbers in the dataset's D column:

(InnerTable, EpNumCol, and MondayRow are named ranges in the example dataset.)
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP($B2:$B, SPLIT(TOCOL(IF(REGEXMATCH(InnerTable, "(?i)\b"&"Timing"&"\b"), EpNumCol&"×"&MondayRow, ), 1), "×"), 2, 0)))

How can I adjust this formula so that it can still match "TIMING LOCK" to the offset episode number in the big dataset?


Here's one approach which you may adapt accordingly:
=map(B2:B,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,ifna(+filter(MondayRow,bycol(filter(InnerTable,scan(,{EpNumCol;""},lambda(a,c,if(istext(c),a,c)))=Σ),lambda(Λ,xmatch(D1,Λ)))),"--"))))



Wow, I'm not sure how this works, but it's really close. I actually need to use a REGEXMATCH instead of an xmatch though, because the text in the dataset isn't always an exact match, nor is it always consistent. I tried changing xmatch(D1,Λ) to REGEXMATCH(InnerTable, "(?i)\b"&"Timing"&"\b") as I had in my original formula, but that doesn't seem to work for some reason?

Use xmatch wildcard search xmatch("*"&D1&"*",Λ,2)

Thanks, that worked great in my example document! But I can't for the life of me figure out why the formula isn't working in my actual document – it just returns "--" for all episode numbers. Everything is the same except for the location of the simplified table's Episode Number column, which I've updated the named range to match. Any idea what I should be looking for to figure this out?

Ah, I figured it out. I guess the MondayRow range has to end at the same column as the InnerTable range.

Also InnerTable rows vary from EpNumCol rows; that's the reason I had to add one virtual row as such {EpNumCol;""}

Ahh, that's a good practice to know for making named ranges in the future, thanks!
